# only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars python

Tags: python, numpy

I’ve recently studied python, when building an amplitude-modulated signal, this error occurs, as I understand it, something is wrong with the data types, but I don’t understand what needs to be specifically fixed. Below I give the function itself and the code with which it works

```
def signal_am(amp, km, fc, fs, period):
     t = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
     return (amp * (1 + km * np.cos(2*pi*fs*t)+2*sin(2*pi*f*t)) * np.cos(fc * t))

N = 1024
fs = 12            
fc = 155
km = [0.5, 1, 1.7]   
sig = [signal_am(amp=1.0, km=i, fc=fc, fs=fs, period=N) for i in km]
```

error:
[image]

Comment: @Snehil Can you tell me how I can fix my code to avoid this?

Comment: in the return statement, what is `f`?

Comment: @MrFuppes its frequency, int number

Comment: ok, if you use variables in a function that are not passed as arguments, it might work if they are defined in the outer namespace of the function. However, I'd consider it *better practice* to pass everything that the function needs as arguments. You function e.g. doesn't actually do anything with `period`, so why pass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, `t` is a 1d numpy array. Not all functions you use seem to accept array input, some might expect scalar values (e.g. `sin`). Use `numpy` [ufuncs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html) instead and it should work:

```
import numpy as np

def signal_am(amp, km, f, fc, fs, period):
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
    return (amp * (1 + km * np.cos(2*np.pi*fs*t)+2*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)) * np.cos(fc * t))

N = 1024
fs = 12            
fc = 155
km = [0.5, 1, 1.7]   
sig = [signal_am(amp=1.0, km=i, f=1, fc=fc, fs=fs, period=N) for i in km]
```